# redirect all files within the same folder to the index page (same folder)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have search for this however cannot seem to find the answer. I have a folder with 50 html pages and the index (home page)
(Don't ask why, it's inherited)

What I'd like to do is redirect all of these 50 files to the index page in the same folder.

Eg. folder/test.html to folder/index.html, folder/test2.html to folder/index.html and so on.

I tried in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^folder/index\.html$
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)\.html$ http://www.domain.com/folder/index.html [R=301]
```

It doesn't work and gets stuck in a loop.
Thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/index\.html$
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.html$ /folder/index.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!

It also seems the L flag needs to be set otherwise it won't work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following.

`RewriteRule ^go/(.*) www.mysite.com/folder/link.php [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: That would have been ok, if I wanted to use a different folder. Redirecting all files to the same folder, which would include the index, would make a loop.